# pdftk - Filling auto-fill PDF form with a FDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox, pdftk, php-pdftk

First of all, thank you for the time you are taking to read my question.

I have a PDF file with a part that, when you fill it, it populates other parts of the PDF.

Basically, you enter your last name and it populates the parts of the PDF that need the last name.

I need to fill the last name with a PHP script that takes the last name from a HTML form. I need to keep the auto-fill feature enabled.

The field_name for the last name is:

```
FieldType: Text
FieldName: MCSA-5875[0].Page1[0].driverPersonal[0].nameLast[0]
FieldNameAlt: Enter the driver's last name.
FieldFlags: 0
FieldJustification: Left
```

The FDF file I created to fill the form is:

```
%FDF-1.2
%,,oe"
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF << /Fields [<</T(MCSA-5875[0].Page1[0].driverPersonal[0].nameLast[0])/V(Smith)>>"] >> >>
endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF;
```

Where "Smith" is a sample last name.

When I run the following command (to fill the PDF form):

```
pdftk form.pdf fill_form output.fdf output output.pdf
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Java Exception in create_output():
java.lang.ClassCastException: pdftk.com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfLiteral cannot be cast to pdftk.com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDictionary
   at 0x0059a84e (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0059ad42 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x005e9bd4 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x005ba4a4 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x005b2044 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0059231e (Unknown Source)
   at 0x004721bd (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00472562 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00472045 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x004df3e2 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x004df38a (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00471e74 (Unknown Source)
```

Can you help me to find a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the pdfbox label? PDFBox is in java, not php.

Comment: If I have to switch to PDFbox, I'd do it.

Comment: If you use PDFBox, then show the code you used and share the PDF... re your current problem, why the quote after Smith?

Comment: You're using PdfTk, which means that you're using an old version of iText (compare my name with the package name in your error message). Why don't you use the most recent version of iText?

Comment: Is iText free to use?

Comment: I'll erase the quote, thank you

Comment: I deleted the quote and it worked but the pdf lost most of its functionalities. I guess I'll have to use iText or PDFbox because pdftk is too all or what?

Comment: I can't comment because I haven't seen the PDF. Nor do I understand what you mean with "lost most of its functionalities".

Comment: Pdftk partially "flattens" the form eventough I didn't ask for that. The form was  made with Adobe LiveCyle and, when I filled the form with PDFtk, it lost some of the auto-fill and interactive features. 

I'm already downloading something java related but it'll be an issue because our hosting doesn't have java support.

Comment: I already know what happened. It lost the XFA functionalities. Problem is, iText need a plugin to fill XFA forms. Does anyone knows about an open source solution to fill XFA forms?

Comment: PDFBox doesn't support XFA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did it! I just used the following open-source solution: https://github.com/Tadelsucht/BulkPDF

We filled the csv template on demand using an HTML form and a PHP backend.

We, then, called the application trough command-line using PHP